# Degenerate, non-degenerate DC-DC converter

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, switching-regulator

Can anyone define what a degenerate DC-DC converter is?

[This](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.68.527&rep=rep1&type=pdf) article mentions a "non-degenerate DC-DC converter" but did not explain it clearly (to me).

Also from the article:

> **Since only non-degenerate converters are of practical importance**, this property implies that in a synthesis of voltaget+voltage converter topologies we should consider only even-order networks with the same number of capacitors and inductors.

Why are only non-degenerate converters of practical importance?

Answer (score 5):

In certain fields, though not *usually* in engineering, the term "degenerate" is used to mean a case of a general class that is also a case of a simpler, more specific class. For instance, in mathematics, a circle could be considered a degenerate ellipse, since most of the mathematics for dealing with ellipses is unnecessarily complicated (though does still work) when talking about circles.

Here, it's saying that a DC-DC converter with a degenerate filter is not of interest. Take for instance this filter:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fl5QO7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The one on the left can be trivially simplified to the one on the right, so despite containing three reactive components (which in general would mean a third-order filter), it is actually only a second-order filter and can be analyzed as such.